# Getting Facebook User ID on a Fanpage is Not Working Anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

This code used to work fine, but now the `user_id` is missing in my `$data` object.  I had in mind, that from the moment the User 'Likes' the page, he isn't anonymous anymore and that you can fetch his ID using this code.  This is the code I have always used:

```
require_once 'assets/requests/facebook-php-sdk-dafef11/src/facebook.php';

$secret = "XXX";
$data = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], $secret);


function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

 // decode the data
 $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
 $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);
 echo ' FUID: ', $fuid = $data['user_id'];    // NO USER ID HERE ANYMORE
 echo '<pre>' , var_dump($data), '</pre>';

 if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
     error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
     return null;
 }

 // check sig
 $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
 if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
     error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!'); 
     return null;
 }

 return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
 return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

`var_dump`ing the `$data` object shows this:

```
array(4) {
  ["algorithm"]=>
  string(11) "HMAC-SHA256"
  ["issued_at"]=>
  int(1321524964)
  ["page"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(15) "227488627318218"
    ["liked"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["admin"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  ["user"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["locale"]=>
    string(5) "de_DE"
    ["age"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["min"]=>
      int(21)
    }
  }
}
```

Did facebook change something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the old fb_sig stuff?  I'm not going to pretend to understand what it means, but fb_sig was removed the other day.  They said it was removed on October 1st, but I think they actually removed it late last week:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/